# The best way to put balls into boxes

Tags: probability, combinatorics, expected-value

There are $36$ identical balls, $12$ boxes numbered $1$ to $12$, and two $6$-sided dice.

You start by placing each of the balls into one of the boxes. You then repeatedly roll the dice and take a ball from the box numbered with their sum. If there isn't any ball in that box, you just skip the round.

> What is the best strategy to assign the balls to minimize the expected number of rounds needed to take all balls out?

I know how to use min-max Inclusion–exclusion principle to solve the problem which the balls are already assigned. But is there an effecient way to find out the best strategy?

And if there is a way to answer the question when the possibility to take a ball from the i-th box is $p_i$.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Can you just put all the 36 balls in the box 7?

Comment: It must not be the best way. For example there are 2 boxes and 2 balls, they have respectively 2/5 and 3/5 ways to be chosen, but it call be easily calculated that the expected rounds needed that you put 2 balls in the second box is 13/6, while it is 5/2 if you put one ball in the first box and the other in the second!

Comment: @Qasis In your last comment, I think the expected time should be $\frac25\cdot \frac53+\frac35\cdot \frac52=\frac{13}6$ when the balls are in different boxes, but $\frac{5}3+\frac53=\frac{10}3$ when they are both in the $\frac35$ box. This still confirms your point.

Answer (score 3):

You can solve the problem recursively as follows.  Let $V(n_2,n_3,\dots,n_{12})$ be the expected number of rounds if there are $n_i$ balls in box $i$.  Then $V(0,0,\dots,0)=0$ and otherwise
\begin{align}V(n_2,n_3,\dots,n_{12}) = 1 
&+ p_2 V((n_2-1)^+,n_3,\dots,n_{12}) \\
&+ p_3 V(n_2,(n_3-1)^+,\dots,n_{12}) \\
&+ \dots + p_{12} V(n_2,n_3,\dots,(n_{12}-1)^+),
\end{align}
where $x^+ = \max(x,0)$.
Equivalently,
\begin{align}V(n_2,n_3,\dots,n_{12}) = \left(1\right. 
&+ [n_2>0]p_2 V(n_2-1,n_3,\dots,n_{12}) \\
&+ [n_3>0]p_3 V(n_2,n_3-1,\dots,n_{12}) \\
&+ \dots + \left.[n_{12}>0]p_{12} V(n_2,n_3,\dots,n_{12}-1)\right) \\
&/ \left(1 - \sum_{i: n_i=0} p_i\right)
\end{align}
Now take the minimum of $V(n_2,n_3,\dots,n_{12})$ over $(n_2,n_3,\dots,n_{12})$ such that $\sum_{i=2}^{12} n_i=36$.

Here are optimal results for up to $18$ balls:
\begin{matrix}
n_2 &n_3 &n_4 &n_5 &n_6 &n_7 &n_8 &n_9 &n_{10} &n_{11} &n_{12} &\sum_i n_i &V \\
\hline
0 &0 &0 &0 &0 &0 &0 &0 &0 &0 &0 &0 &0.0000 \\
0 &0 &0 &0 &0 &1 &0 &0 &0 &0 &0 &1 &6.0000 \\
0 &0 &0 &0 &1 &1 &0 &0 &0 &0 &0 &2 &9.9273 \\
0 &0 &0 &0 &1 &1 &1 &0 &0 &0 &0 &3 &12.5045 \\
0 &0 &0 &1 &1 &1 &1 &0 &0 &0 &0 &4 &15.4760 \\
0 &0 &0 &1 &1 &1 &1 &1 &0 &0 &0 &5 &17.7678 \\
0 &0 &0 &1 &1 &2 &1 &1 &0 &0 &0 &6 &19.7617 \\
0 &0 &0 &1 &2 &2 &1 &1 &0 &0 &0 &7 &22.2788 \\
0 &0 &0 &1 &2 &2 &2 &1 &0 &0 &0 &8 &24.3058 \\
0 &0 &1 &1 &2 &2 &2 &1 &0 &0 &0 &9 &26.4305 \\
0 &0 &1 &1 &2 &3 &2 &1 &0 &0 &0 &10 &28.2668 \\
0 &0 &1 &1 &2 &3 &2 &1 &1 &0 &0 &11 &29.8650 \\
0 &0 &1 &2 &2 &3 &2 &1 &1 &0 &0 &12 &31.9219 \\
0 &0 &1 &2 &2 &3 &2 &2 &1 &0 &0 &13 &33.6995 \\
0 &0 &1 &2 &3 &3 &2 &2 &1 &0 &0 &14 &35.4759 \\
0 &0 &1 &2 &3 &3 &3 &2 &1 &0 &0 &15 &37.0159 \\
0 &0 &1 &2 &3 &4 &3 &2 &1 &0 &0 &16 &38.4390 \\
0 &0 &1 &2 &3 &5 &3 &2 &1 &0 &0 &17 &40.6388 \\
0 &0 &1 &2 &4 &5 &3 &2 &1 &0 &0 &18 &42.6650 \\
\end{matrix}

Comment: It appears doing in in proportion to the probability of each sum is not correct.  You put more in the $7$ bin and fewer in the outlying bins that that would suggest.  That makes a certain sense.  The worst bin will take something like the $+1.5\sigma$ time, so you should have extra balls in the bins with small $\sigma$  That would suggest that for a large number of balls you would approach the probability of each bin for the fraction of balls.

Comment: @RossMillikan - May I suggest you write an Answer (one of those "too long for a comment" type Answers) to explain the $1.5$ factor in your $+1.5 \sigma$ argument?  If I guess correctly what you're thinking, then IMHO the heuristic reasoning is worth sharing, even though it doesn't rigorously answer the OP question.  Also, one can try to see if it matches RobPratt's results for e.g. $18$.

Comment: @antkam:  The idea is that the boxes are in a contest to be the last to be emptied.  Some will be emptied faster than average because their number comes up more often, some slower.  I  got $1.5\sigma$ from guessing how bad the worst of $12$ would be.  Only $2.5\%$ are $2\sigma$ above the mean, but $16\%$ are $1\sigma$ high, so somewhere around $1.5\sigma$ seems reasonable.

Comment: @RossMillikan - I was able to "reverse-engineer" your $1.5$ factor, and my comment was simply saying IMHO that's worth an Answer.  Your standards (for an Answer) are apparently higher than mine as you seem happy explaining it in just a comment.  :)  Either way, thank you!

Comment: Back to Rob's excellent simulation (+1 BTW).  What I find most curious is the transition from $\sum n = 9$ to $10$.  The pattern of "where to add the next ball" is always  "maximally(?)" symmetric in the sense that either the pattern before adding the ball or the pattern after is symmetric -- except for $9$ to $10$, which is the only transition/addition in which an asym pattern is followed by another asym pattern.

Comment: @antkam, $V(0,0,1,1,2,2,2,1,1,0,0)=28.280356757$ is slightly worse than the minimum for $10$.

Comment: @RobPratt - I don't doubt your result at all!  (Sorry if I gave the wrong impression.) I just find it interesting that even a (IMHO) very basic "symmetry" property does not hold - i.e. the patterns do not return to symmetry "as soon as possible".

Comment: @antkam, no problem.  Based on your observation, I had my own doubt, so I checked this value to be sure.

Answer (score 1):

You know that rolling two dices has 36 different outcomes and 12 different sums.
You should try to see how many different rolls has $i$ as sum and put that many balls in the box number $i$.
For example in the box number $7$ you should put $6$ different balls becuse rolling the dices you can get a $7$ in $6$ different ways $\{(1,6),\dots,(6,1)\}$.
In this way you are more likely to always remove a ball when you throw the dices.

Comment: Can you please prove why it is the best way that you put the number of balls proportional to the possibilty of each box? And what would happen when the numbers of balls in each box is not an integer?

Comment: I don't know how to prove this in a rigorous way. I think that you could try saying that if you repeat the "game" over and over and you consider the medium number of turns needed to empty the boxes you could use the central limit theorem.

Anyway, in this case the number of balls in each box is always an integer because you have 36 different outcomes rolling two dices and you have 36 balls.

Comment: But in the further discussed problems which the i-th box has probabilty $p_i$ to be chosen, as the number of balls is dispersed, it might have some trouble. But anyway, thank you very much.